# ReactJS: using connect to dispatch actions from two separate files

Tags: reactjs, redux

Beginner question, I have the following code:

```
import * as actions from "../../store/actions/supActions";

class Home extends Component {
      //.
      //.
      //.
      //actions from supActions are called somewhere here
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      bla: state.bla
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home);
```

In the above, I am calling a number of action functions from within the `supActions` file, so it made sense to import them all as `actions`, and pass `actions` to the `connect` function second parameter.

However, now I want to use another action from a different file. I imported it but I am not sure how I am supposed to edit the `connect` function parameters to include it:

```
import * as actions from "../../store/actions/supActions";
import {newAction} from "../../store/actions/roleActions";

class Home extends Component {
      //.
      //.
      //.
      //actions from supActions are called somewhere here
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      bla: state.bla
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home); // how to add the newAction here?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can destructure old actions and join with the new action in a new object by doing so:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {...actions, newAction})(Home);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Actions` in this case is really just an object.

What you can do is create a new object and add the newAction into it. We are just creating a new object that includes all the `actions` and `newAction`

```
import * as actions from "../../store/actions/supActions";
import {newAction} from "../../store/actions/roleActions";

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  newAction,
  ...actions
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```